# Woocommerce subscription WC()->cart->add_to_cart monthly is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, woocommerce-subscriptions

We are selecting the number of products to insert in cart. We are using woocommerce subscription plugin for variation on yearly and monthly basis.

if We are selecting 5 products to insert in cart we are using the while loop for getting variation product related to monthly and yearly with count 5 and using code to insert in cart as.

```
 WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $parent_id, $quantity = 1, $variation_id );
```

it is not working with this code as we want 5 different products to add in cart. but is use the code with variation_id it is working but the product remains the same.

```
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $parent_id, $quantity = 1, $variation_id = 2918 );
```

this code is working but with the same product 5 times.

Need help for it Thanks